# Error in applying Pascal's theorem

Tags: geometry, circles

$A,C, F$ are random $3$ points on a circle and $O,S$ are random points on $AC$. $FS$ meets the circle again at $R$ and $FO$ meets the circle again at $Y$. $RO$ meets the circle at $G$.

[image]

Now if we apply [Pascal's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) on hexagon $ARYCGF$,

> $AC \cap RF=S, RG \cap FY=O, YC \cap AG$ should be collinear.

But clearly that's impossible since the first two intersections make line $AC$ but the last intersection point is surely not on $AC$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should look more carefully at statement of the theorem and at the order in which letters appear. In particular, I suggest to rename the points $A_1,\dots , A_6$ to better see what happens.

Comment: $AC \cap RF$ is not correct intersection for Pascal's theorem. AC connects opposite vertices and RF -- not. There is no such option in Pascal's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your illustration shows that $RG \cap FY \cap AC =O$. To form [the Pascal line of a hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem), there should be three intersections, each of them being made by a pair of line segments.

Also please note that line segments are drawn between the opposite side of a hexagon.